# Clash between tcolorbox and amsfonts

Tags: tcolorbox, blackboard, amsfonts

I get error messages when I use `\mathbb` in the heading of a tcolorbox theorem. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem{boxtheorem}{Theorem}{}{thm}
\begin{document}
\begin{boxtheorem}{This is the problem: $\mathbb{N}$}{}
This is fine: $\mathbb{N}$
\end{boxtheorem}
\end{document}
```

Here are the four error messages:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...

! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                              \let \@err@               ...

! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                              \@empty \def \MessageBreak...

! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                 \endgroup
```

I use MiKTeX 2.9. It is newly installed, and all packages and formats are updated. Surprisingly, that seems to be the problem: when I compile the same document on another computer with older packages, there are no problems. But having to rely on older packages is not sustainable in the long run, so I need to figure out how to solve the problem with the newest packages. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Update

As of `tcolorbox` version 3.96, released 2016/11/18, the bug has been fixed.

## Original answer

It's a bad bug in `tcolorbox`: the macro `\tcb@gettitle` does `\edef` instead of `\protected@edef`, so ***many*** commands will fail, not only `\mathbb` (think to `\emph`, for instance).

You can fix it by redefining the bad macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem{boxtheorem}{Theorem}{}{thm}

\makeatletter
\def\tcb@gettitle#1{\protected@edef\@currentlabelname{#1}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{boxtheorem}{This is the \emph{problem}: $\mathbb{N}$}{}
This is fine: $\mathbb{N}$
\end{boxtheorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Filed report at https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/14

Comment: I will fix this soon following your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: while obviously this is the better approach, loading `tcolorbox` *before* `amsfonts` does produce output.

Answer (score 6):

You can make the command robust:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem{boxtheorem}{Theorem}{}{thm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\mathbb
\begin{document}
\begin{boxtheorem}{This is the problem: $\mathbb{N}$}{}
This is fine: $\mathbb{N}$
\end{boxtheorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Now try with `\emph{problem}`. `;-)`